# kill -9 でプロセスが消えずApacheが起動できません。

Tags: apache, amazon-linux

Amazon Linux2環境です。

以下を実行

```
$ sudo systemctl start httpd.service
```

以下のエラーが出てきました。

```
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[ec2-user@ip-w-x-y-z www]$ sudo systemctl status httpd.service
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service.d
           └─php-fpm.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) 
     Docs: man:httpd.service(8)
  Process: 3650 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 3650 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "Reading configuration..."

: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
: no listening sockets available, shutting down

systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

Address already in use: とあったのでプロセスを調べてみることにしてました。

```
$  sudo lsof -i | grep http
nginx    3109     root    6u  IPv4  18588      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx    3109     root    7u  IPv6  18589      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx    3110    nginx    6u  IPv4  18588      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx    3110    nginx    7u  IPv6  18589      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

```
$ sudo kill -9 3109
```

を試してみましたが・・

```
$  sudo lsof -i | grep http
nginx    3109     root    6u  IPv4  18588      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx    3109     root    7u  IPv6  18589      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx    3110    nginx    6u  IPv4  18588      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx    3110    nginx    7u  IPv6  18589      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

消えませんでした・・

どうすればApache起動できるようになるでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

同じwebサーバの Nginx が起動しており80番のポートを先に使用しているからだと思いますが、同時に稼働させる必要がなければ、まず Nginx を停止してから Apache の起動を試してください。

```
$ sudo systemctl stop nginx
$ sudo systemctl disable nginx
```

Answer (score 0):

> $ sudo kill -9 3109
> を試してみましたが・・

`kill -9` ですが、実行するとシグナルハンドリングなどもスキップしてプロセスが強制終了されるので、ゾンビプロセスが発生したり、ソケットのようなシステムリソースが解放されないままになったりするので、特に長期サーバ運用時の利用には注意が必要です。

なので @cubick さんの回答のように、systemctlによる順当なnginx停止をまず試すべきだったんだろうと思います。